# what is the $2n+1$ derivative of $\frac{f(x)}{a^x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$ f(x)=\frac{x^n(1-x)^n}{n!} $$
What is
$$ \frac{d^{2n+1}}{dx^{2n+1}} \frac{f(x)}{a^x}$$
?

I used wolfram and it seems that it's equal to $a^{-x} (f^{2n}(x)+f^{2n-1}(x)+\cdots+f(x))$, with some constants multiplying $f's$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It might be a good idea to compute it for $n=1$ and look for a pattern.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Higher_derivatives